# Sorting Variables and negated Variables in Java

Tags: java

how to sort variables X and negated varibles X' alphabetic which are saved as string in Java?

```
Example: String string = "B*A'*D*H'"; result must
         String sortedString="A'*B*D*H'";
```

Comment: You haven't given *nearly* enough information. Your sample strings aren't even valid string literals, and we have no idea what they would even mean. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints - we want to help you, but you need to put more effort into asking a question we can answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

are the variables always separated with `*` ?
In that case it'd be very simple:

```
    String in = "B*A'*D*H'";
    String[] vars = in.split("\\*");

    Arrays.sort(vars);

    // Java is missing a simple php-like join function ;-(
    StringBuilder sorted = new StringBuilder();
    for(String s: vars){
        sorted.append(s);
        sorted.append("*");
    }
    sorted.deleteCharAt(sorted.length()-1);
```

and you're done ;-)